# Transient Loop Not working as expected

Tags: php, loop, get-posts, transient

So I created a transient object that used `get_posts()` to get a series of posts based on some argument. Well the transient was stored - it was created - YAY - now I tried to write this loop:

```
public function transient_loop($transient_name){
    global $post;
    if(false !== get_transient($transient_name)){
        foreach(get_transient($transient_name) as $post){
            setup_postdata($post);
            $this->_loop_content();
        }
    }
}
```

This looks for the transient name, if it exists, loops over it - sets up the post data and then from there calls a method that goes through and does typical loop stuff, like images, title, links and more - all your typical jazz,

Now what came back was: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/query.php on line 3645`

The stack trace sais the last thing called was the `setup_postdata($post)` so I var dumped `$post` and got `int 1`

Not sure if that's normal. So I decided to var_dump the transient - maybe a post or set of posts is not coming through at all.

**Note:** I am using xdebug - thats why the object is all formatted nicely. But I did: `var_dump($transient_name)` and got back:

```
object(WP_Post)[259]
  public 'ID' => int 1
  public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'post_date' => string '2013-08-16 22:57:23' (length=19)
  public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2013-08-16 22:57:23' (length=19)
  public 'post_content' => string 'Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!' (length=86)
  public 'post_title' => string 'Hello world!' (length=12)
  public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
  public 'comment_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
  public 'ping_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
  public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_name' => string 'hello-world' (length=11)
  public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_modified' => string '2013-08-16 22:57:23' (length=19)
  public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2013-08-16 22:57:23' (length=19)
  public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_parent' => int 0
  public 'guid' => string 'http://localhost/wordpress/?p=1' (length=31)
  public 'menu_order' => int 0
  public 'post_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
  public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'comment_count' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
  public 'format_content' => null
```

So what's with the error?

Comment: So `$transient_name` is a post object? the function [`get_transient`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient) aspect a string as argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct way to do this is not fail at spelling, its `get_posts()` not `get_post`

Answer (score 0):

What is the code on line 3645? You didn't specify.

From what I see in your code, $transient_name should be something like "_my_post_list_transient" - a string.

If $transient_name is returning a post object, then your call to this function may be the problem.

Comment: `$transient_name` is pretty simple to see what it does. It gives you the sting of the name of the transient. So if you have a transient called "bobs_posts_on_dead_people" that's what get's passed into the function. Its `get_transient($transient_name)` that returns the post object ... Any ways, as for 3645 - I don't know - that's WordPress core. I assumed some one here would know this error from dealing with transients... I can go searching for it and post it if you would like ..

Comment: Apologies, I misread the function name. 

I see that $transient_name is supposed to have the name, but where you var_dump it, you get back an OBJECT not a string.

setup_postdata($post) is expecting to be passed a post object, not the integer that you've given it.

I still suspect that your $transient_name is not the string you think it is coming into this function.

Comment: Jeff, I am var dumping `get_transient($transient_name)` this function RETURNS you a post object OR false. thats why your suppose to be doing `if(false === get_transient('some_name')){}else{}`  My code is very similar to this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/speed-up-your-wordpress-by-caching-custom-queries-using-transients-api/

Comment: You should update the original question then. In that you state "var_dump($transient_name)" brings back a post object. If your question isn't accurate, no answer can help.